# Replace time in status bar - iOS app

Tags: ios, statusbar

Trying to dynamically adjust the time in the status bar in iOS development; to change to a timer or other text in certain views. Can this be done without dynamically hiding/showing the entire status bar? Just trying to replace the time in varying views while keeping the native status bar.

Comment: No, you can not access the statusbar, you will have to hide the hole statusbar and replace it with your own. This ofcours will mean that you lose the network and batter status.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot access / adjust / edit the status bar. The most customization you can do is: Hide and change status bar color. You'll have to hide the status bar and show your own UIView in place of it.

Comment: A answer down-vote without a reason does not help and does not allow the answerer to correct the answer. Thus I will up-vote to correct.